# How to set my control on top of others in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a tab control  in which I have modified the template.  The goal is to put a Toggle button to the right of the group of TabItems and above the TabContent.  This works.  When the Toggle button is clicked I need bring up panel that appears underneath my Toggle Button but sits over the TabContent.

I thought I could achieve this with ZIndex but thus far I have been unsuccessful.  The "window" either sits behind the TabContent or pushes out the Tab area.

```
<Style  TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="20">
                        <TabPanel Grid.Row="0" Panel.ZIndex="1"  Margin="0,0,4,-1"  IsItemsHost="True" Background="Transparent" />
                            <UniformGrid Columns="3" Rows="1" Height="20" Width="500" Margin="150,0,0,0">
                                <WrapPanel Height="20">
                                    <Label Content="Status" Margin="0,0,5,0" Padding="0,0,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="Auto" />
                                    <ToggleButton Height="18" Padding="0,0,0,0">
                                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                                                <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="StatusOverlay" PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                            </i:EventTrigger>
                                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                                                <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="StatusOverlay" PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </i:EventTrigger>
                                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <WrapPanel Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                            <Path Style="{StaticResource StatusSuccess}" />
                                            <Path Style="{StaticResource StatusFailure}" />
                                            <Path Style="{StaticResource StatusSuccess}" />
                                        </WrapPanel> 
                                    </ToggleButton>
                                </WrapPanel>

                                <!-- Placeholder for another item-->
                                <WrapPanel Height="20"> 
                                </WrapPanel>

                                <!-- Placeholder for another item-->
                                <WrapPanel Height="20"> 
                                </WrapPanel> 
                            </UniformGrid> 
                        </StackPanel>

                        <!-- This would be the Panel I want to sit on top -->
                        <Border x:Name="StatusOverlay" Panel.ZIndex="99"  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="403"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="325" Background="#FFD9D9D9" CornerRadius="6" Visibility="Collapsed">

                        </Border>
                        <Border Panel.ZIndex="1" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black"  BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0, 12, 12, 12" > 
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush>
                                    <GradientStop Color="LightBlue" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset=".5" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9245e47b-5fe7-40eb-9822-12f0e48caace/changing-zindex-at-runtime?forum=wpf

Comment: I'm just guessing--move the Border with ZIndex=99 to be before the StackPanel.  So it would be Border StackPanel Border.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why stuff all of this into a Style Template for a TabControl instead of just making a UserControl since I assume it's to be used elsewhere also?

Comment: @Chris W. Do you mean move that status panel I'm trying to hide and show off the tab template or do you mean ditching the tab control all together?

Comment: Ya as in separating out some of your objects instead of throwing them into the style template of one of them.